# .floatright class wont float right

Tags: html, css

Hello im having trouble getting my windingroad.gif to float to the right of my page but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have tried everything but I must be missing something. I would really appreciate some help.

```css
body { background-color: #ffffcc;
      background-image: url(background.gif);
      color: #330000;
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
#wrapper { width: 80%;
           margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     background-color: #ffffcc;
     min-width: 700px;
     max-width: 1024px;
     box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333333;
}
header { background-color: #ccaa66;
  background-image:url("javalogo.gif");
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
       color: #000000;
    height:100px;
}
h1 {margin:0;
   text-indent:100%;
   white-space:nowrap;
   overflow:hidden;
}
h2 { text-transform:uppercase;
  background-color:#ffffcc;
  color:#663300;
  font-size:1.2em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
  padding:5px 0 0 5px;
  margin-right:20px;
  clear: left;
}
nav  { text-align: center; 
   float:left;
   width:100px;
   font-weight:bold;
   padding-top:10px;
   
/* unvisited link */
nav a:link {
    color: #996633;
{
/* visited link */
nav a:visited {
 color: #ccaa66;
}

/* mouse over link */
nav a:hover {
    color: #330000;
}

nav ul {list-style-type:none;
}


   
}
footer { background-color: #ccaa66;
       color: #000000;
    font-size: .60em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    clear:both;
    
    
}
main { padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin-left:150px;
    background-color:#f2eab7;
    color:#000000;
    overflow:auto;

}
.details { padding-left: 20%;
           padding-right: 20%;
     overflow:auto;
}
img { border-style: none; }

nav a {text-decoration:none;
   padding-bottom:15px;
}

.floatright {float: right;
   padding-left:20px;
}

.floatleft{float: left;
     padding-right:20px;
     padding-bottom:bottom;
}

header,nav,main,footer{display:block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javajam.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
 <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
 <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<main>
<p>Follow the winding road to JavaJam...</p>
<img src="windingroad.jpg" class="floatright" alt="winding road through the woods"
height="156" width="333">
  <ul>
    <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
    <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
    <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
    <li>Open Mic Night</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
12312 Main Street<br>
Mountain Home, CA 93923<br>
1-888-555-5555<br>
<br>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2014 JavaJam Coffee House<br>
<a href="mailto:yourfirstname@yourlastname.com">yourfirstname@yourlastname.com</a>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the CSS :
1. you have not closed the nav with "}" in the nav{} block.
2. instead of "}" you have put open bracket at the end of the nav a:link block.

```
nav  { text-align: center; 
      float:left;
      width:100px;
      font-weight:bold;
      padding-top:10px;

/* unvisited link */
nav a:link {
    color: #996633;
{
```

The above code should be made like so :

```
nav  { text-align: center; 
      float:left;
      width:100px;
      font-weight:bold;
      padding-top:10px;
     } 
/* unvisited link */
nav a:link {
    color: #996633;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    body { background-color: #ffffcc;
      background-image: url(background.gif);
      color: #330000;
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
#wrapper { width: 80%;
           margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     background-color: #ffffcc;
     min-width: 700px;
     max-width: 1024px;
     box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333333;
}
header { background-color: #ccaa66;
  background-image:url("javalogo.gif");
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
       color: #000000;
    height:100px;
}
h1 {margin:0;
   text-indent:100%;
   white-space:nowrap;
   overflow:hidden;
}
h2 { text-transform:uppercase;
  background-color:#ffffcc;
  color:#663300;
  font-size:1.2em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
  padding:5px 0 0 5px;
  margin-right:20px;
  clear: left;
}
nav  { text-align: center; 
   float:left;
   width:100px;
   font-weight:bold;
   padding-top:10px;
}
/* unvisited link */
nav a:link {
    color: #996633;
}
/* visited link */
nav a:visited {
 color: #ccaa66;
}

/* mouse over link */
nav a:hover {
    color: #330000;
}

nav ul {list-style-type:none;
}


   
}
footer { background-color: #ccaa66;
       color: #000000;
    font-size: .60em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    clear:both;
    
    
}
main { padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin-left:150px;
    background-color:#f2eab7;
    color:#000000;
    overflow:auto;

}
.details { padding-left: 20%;
           padding-right: 20%;
     overflow:auto;
}
img { border-style: none; }

nav a {text-decoration:none;
   padding-bottom:15px;
}

.floatright {float: right;
   padding-left:20px;
}

.floatleft{float: left;
     padding-right:20px;
     padding-bottom:bottom;
}

header,nav,main,footer{display:block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javajam.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
 <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
 <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<main>
<p>Follow the winding road to JavaJam...</p>
<img src="windingroad.jpg" style = "float:right;" alt="winding road through the woods"
height="156" width="333">
  <ul>
    <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
    <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
    <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
    <li>Open Mic Night</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
12312 Main Street<br>
Mountain Home, CA 93923<br>
1-888-555-5555<br>
<br>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2014 JavaJam Coffee House<br>
<a href="mailto:yourfirstname@yourlastname.com">yourfirstname@yourlastname.com</a>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Add `style = "float:right;"` on Img

[image]

Comment: OP's CSS file is borked.This definitely solves this issue, but still leaves other alignment issues.

Comment: Yes , we miss the div , however, in response to his question this is the ultimate solution ... clearly to use css should rearrange the structure html .

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with your CSS file.There are a lot of unclosed brackets.I've attached some below:

```
nav  { text-align: center; 
      float:left;
      width:100px;
      font-weight:bold;
      padding-top:10px;
      <-----------------------THIS IS NOT CLOSED----->
/* unvisited link */
nav a:link {
    color: #996633;
       <-----------------------THIS IS NOT CLOSED----->
{ <-----------------------Extra bracket opened----->
/* visited link */
nav a:visited {
    color: #ccaa66;
}
```

It's working fine.

```css
body { background-color: #ffffcc;
      background-image: url(background.gif);
      color: #330000;
      font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
#wrapper { width: 80%;
           margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     background-color: #ffffcc;
     min-width: 700px;
     max-width: 1024px;
     box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333333;
}
header { background-color: #ccaa66;
  background-image:url("javalogo.gif");
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
       color: #000000;
    height:100px;
}
h1 {margin:0;
   text-indent:100%;
   white-space:nowrap;
   overflow:hidden;
}
h2 { text-transform:uppercase;
  background-color:#ffffcc;
  color:#663300;
  font-size:1.2em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
  padding:5px 0 0 5px;
  margin-right:20px;
  clear: left;
}
nav  { text-align: center; 
   float:left;
   width:100px;
   font-weight:bold;
   padding-top:10px;
}
/* unvisited link */
nav a:link {
    color: #996633;
}

/* visited link */
nav a:visited {
 color: #ccaa66;
}

/* mouse over link */
nav a:hover {
    color: #330000;
}

nav ul {list-style-type:none;
}


   

footer { background-color: #ccaa66;
       color: #000000;
    font-size: .60em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    clear:both;
    
    
}
main { padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin-left:150px;
    background-color:#f2eab7;
    color:#000000;
    overflow:auto;

}
.details { padding-left: 20%;
           padding-right: 20%;
     overflow:auto;
}
img { border-style: none; }

nav a {text-decoration:none;
   padding-bottom:15px;
}

.floatright {float: right;
   padding-left:20px;
}

.floatleft{float: left;
     padding-right:20px;
     padding-bottom:bottom;
}

header,nav,main,footer{display:block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="javajam.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
 <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
 <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<main>
<p>Follow the winding road to JavaJam...</p>
<img src="windingroad.jpg" class="floatright" alt="winding road through the woods"
height="156" width="333">
  <ul>
    <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
    <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
    <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
    <li>Open Mic Night</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
12312 Main Street<br>
Mountain Home, CA 93923<br>
1-888-555-5555<br>
<br>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2014 JavaJam Coffee House<br>
<a href="mailto:yourfirstname@yourlastname.com">yourfirstname@yourlastname.com</a>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```